# How to handle built-in(?) command as a parameter in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, bash, cat, getopt

I want to make a program similar to "cat" that reads a text file.
ex) mycat abc.txt

And I add a few options such as "<" but it cannot read < as a parameter. ex) mycat < abc.txt
I am trying to use getopt function and other option works well except for "<".
How do I handle a command "<" as a parameter for my program in Linux?

Comment: How are you passing "<" to your program? It's handled specially by the shell so if you really want to pass it to your program, you'll have to escape or quote it. Like `mycat "<" abc.txt`

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you! Thats what I need. It helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` is not a parameter that the program reads.  It's a shell input redirection.  It means that the shell will make the specified file the `stdin` of the program.

What this means for you is that if you don't get any parameters then you read from `stdin`.